# Importing graph files into LaTeX

Tags: graphics

I have a few graphs for a lab report I am writing and was wondering how you would go about import these files into LaTeX. They are PostScript files so LaTeX accepts them.

Comment: The "normal"/original LaTeX compiler which produces DVI output will accept PostScript files ((E)PS) and pass them along to the DVI2PS converter (e.g. `dvips`). However, if you want PDF output it might be necessary to convert them to PDF first using `epstopdf`. Newer versions of the LaTeX compiler try to do this automatically.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is very simple use a document like this

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{graph-in-eps-format}
\end{document}
```

Of course you may want to have a caption so you should put it in a floating environment

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{graph-in-eps-format}
\caption{A graph}
\label{a-label.for-reference}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Simple things like this are usually covered in every basic latex introduction such as e.g. [l2short.pdf](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/lshort/english/)